# Why does one HTTP GET request retrieve the required data and another retrieve []

Tags: mongodb, rest, http, get, ng-admin

I'm currently working on ng-admin.

I'm having a problem retrieving user data from my REST API (connected to a MongoDB) and displaying it.

I have identified the problem as the following:

When I enter `http://localhost:3000/users` into my browser, I get a list of all users in my database.

When I enter `http://localhost:3000/users?_page=1&_perPage=30&_sortDir=DESC&_sortField=id`,
I get `[]` as a result.

I am quite new to this, I used both my browser and the POSTMAN Chrome extension to test this and get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://localhost:3000/users_end=30&_order=DESC&_sort=id&_start=0
```

This (`/users_end`) is a different request than `/users`.

It should be:

```
http://localhost:3000/users?end=30&_order=DESC&_sort=id&_start=0
```

Or, by looking at the other parameters:

```
http://localhost:3000/users?_end=30&_order=DESC&_sort=id&_start=0
```

with `end` or `_end` being the first parameter (mark the `?`).

---

**Update** (it is ? and before the _, I have edited.):

If adding parameters to the request returns an empty list, try adding only one at a time to narrow down the problem (there's probably an error in the usage of those parameters - are you sure you need those underscores?).

Answer (score 0):

Your REST API must have a way to handle pagination, sorting, and filtering. But ng-admin cannot determine exactly how, because REST is a style and not a standard. So ng-admin makes assumptions about how your API does that by default, that's why it adds these `_end` and `_sort` query parameters.

In order to transform these parameters into those that your API understands, you'll have to add an interceptor. This is all thoroughly explained in the ng-admin documentation: http://ng-admin-book.marmelab.com/doc/API-mapping.html

Comment: My API doesn't allow me to sort, or paginate, does that mean I cannot use ng-admin

Comment: You can still use ng-admin, but you'll have to remove the sorting and pagination query parameters in an interceptor.

Comment: Apologies, your documentation expresses these concepts clearly, I didn't understand before.